# How do I make numbers 0-100 using only the numbers 2, 0, 0, 4 in order?

Tags: mathematics

Please help me I need to find out how to do this with maths.

Comment: Is there any limit to the operations that can be used?

Comment: 101 equations is quite a lot. Can you narrow it down to the ones you can't do?

Comment: Can the numbers be concatenated? For example the obvious $200 / 4$?

Answer (score 2):

> $$0=2\times0\times0\times4$$
>  $$1=2^0+0\times4$$
>  $$2=2^{0!} \times (0!)^4$$

Comment: I've added LaTeX formatting to your answer, to make it look nicely. Also, the answer is now hidden behind a spoiler, to prevent early reading of it by the users who view the question.